# image is not setting in the ImageView inside a listView with a cursor

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, simplecursoradapter

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            MainActivity.this, R.layout.user, cursor, from, to)

    {

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String s = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_SEX"));
            final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View sexxx = inflater.inflate(R.layout.user, null);
                sexlogo = (ImageView) sexxx.findViewById(R.id.sex);

            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("Male"))
                sexlogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);

            else 
                sexlogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);
            return row;
        }
    };
```

am new to Android, the app adds a user to `SQLite databse`then retrieves all users found in the database to a `ListView` using a `cursor`.

i want to check user's sex and then set him a logo after retrieving his data from database and before adding him to the `listView`.

i have edited my question and added the code above, the app didn't crash moreover images didn't appear .

any help please

Comment: If you're gonna filter the sex and change its image based on it's gender you should use Custom Adapters not a SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: @Cjames i have edited the question,please chech it again.

Comment: avoid using listview position as reference of the cursor just used your db Id

Comment: @Cjames can you explain more pleasee, i have been stuck into this for hours

Comment: There's a big posiblity that the position of the data in database is not exist. The listview position may limit based on the screen size of the devic, therfore it is not wise to use the position of the listview to get the position of the data. Used id on it.

Comment: @Cjames i checked the logcat , am retreiving all data corectly , any suggestion  please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct answer , just remove `LayoutInflater` since the `super` already inflates it .

inflating a `layout` will return a new `root`representing the `xml`

```
{

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            cursor.moveToPosition(position);
            String s = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("USER_SEX"));
            final View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

            sexlogo = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.sex);

            if (s.equals("Male"))
                sexlogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.male);

            else
                sexlogo.setImageResource(R.drawable.female);

            return row;

        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getView` function must return the view to be displayed.

This code returns `row`, which is the view created by the superclass.
The custom image is in the `sexxx` view, which is unused.

Comment: yeah that's right , i answered the question with the right code